# My plate has some parts half black and half-white when its supposed to be only white

Tags: rendering, shaders

So my plate has a white ceramic texture attached to it (color, roughness and normal map) but when I enter rendered mode (only in Cycles) there are some parts half black, I already tried checking the normals with SHift + N and tweaking some material values but that didn't work, please help :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: It kinda looks like your UV map is messed up. Could you post the UV’s?

Comment: dose your plate have different layers ?, if it dose try checking which layer is inside of your main layer,

Comment: @RobinBetts I added the file already

Comment: @cxrxzxnxdx  Thanks :) Late here.. will check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem, your original material is not working properly.

Go to *Material Properties*, and delete your original material, then add a new white material to the plate.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I tried deleting the material and adding it again and same thing happened. Does that mean that there´s an error in the texture file I used? Or did I just map it wrong in the Shading nodes?

Comment: There might be something wrong at least with the nodes connected to the *Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF* node in the Shading Editor because by removing the link, the black area disappeared. But as I am using version 3.6.8, this might be related to lost information during transfer from version 4...

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here, first thing in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to remove all the overlapping vertices. Also display the face orientation and flip all the red faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*. At last <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*. It looks like it will mess up a geonode particle system, you’ll need to fix that as well.